# dplyr case when between

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to join two data sets and in first data set if the date is between StartDate and EndDate, 1 as added as coulmn names pros_sales. Below is my datasets

```
data1=data.frame(Date=as.Date("2015-06-28"),Storecode=34)
data2=data.frame(Promo=c("Promo1","Promo2","Promo3","Promo4")
,StartDate=c("2015-02-10","2015-03-15"," 2015-05-24","2015-06-21")
,EndDate=c("2015-02-17","2015-03-22","2015-06-01","2015-06-28"))
data1$Date <- as.Date(data1$Date) 
data2$StartDate <- as.Date(data2$StartDate) 
data2$EndDate <- as.Date(data2$EndDate)
```

My desired dataset below;

```
 Date Storecode  Promo  StartDate    EndDate         pro_sales
2015-06-28        34 Promo1 2015-02-10 2015-02-17         0
2015-06-28        34 Promo2 2015-03-15 2015-03-22         0
2015-06-28        34 Promo3 2015-05-24 2015-06-01         0
2015-06-28        34 Promo4 2015-06-21 2015-06-28         1
```

Below is my code but it added 1 to all pro_sales.

```
 data.frame( data1 %>%
         mutate(dummy=TRUE) %>%
         left_join(data2 %>% mutate(dummy=TRUE)) %>% 
         mutate(pro_sales = case_when(
           Date>=StartDate | Date<=EndDate ~ 1,
           FALSE ~ 0)))
```

Can you help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
data1=data.frame(Date=as.Date("2015-06-28"), Storecode=34, tmp = 1)
data2=data.frame(Promo=c("Promo1","Promo2","Promo3","Promo4"),
                 StartDate=c("2015-02-10","2015-03-15"," 2015-05-24","2015-06-21"),
                 EndDate=c("2015-02-17","2015-03-22","2015-06-01","2015-06-28"),
                 tmp = 1)
data1$Date <- as.Date(data1$Date) 
data2$StartDate <- as.Date(data2$StartDate) 
data2$EndDate <- as.Date(data2$EndDate) 


full_join(data1, data2, by = "tmp") %>% 
     select(-tmp) %>% 
     mutate(pro_sales = case_when(
          Date>=StartDate & Date<=EndDate ~ 1,
          TRUE ~ 0))
#>         Date Storecode  Promo  StartDate    EndDate pro_sales
#> 1 2015-06-28        34 Promo1 2015-02-10 2015-02-17         0
#> 2 2015-06-28        34 Promo2 2015-03-15 2015-03-22         0
#> 3 2015-06-28        34 Promo3 2015-05-24 2015-06-01         0
#> 4 2015-06-28        34 Promo4 2015-06-21 2015-06-28         1
```

Created on 2018-05-26 by the reprex package (v0.2.0).